# private method `prepend' called for Refinery::Admin::PagesController:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, refinerycms

I'm having an issue with heroku not running my app.

I'm using refinerycms and trying to put my nav menu in the footer per [this tutorial](http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/menu-presenter).

I pushed everything to heroku successfully.

`heroku run rake db:migrate` worked fine.

When I try to open the app on heroku, I get this error in the logs:

```
/app/app/decorators/controllers/refinery/pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': private method `prepend' called for Refinery::Admin::PagesController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

This is the file causing the error:
`pages_controller_decorator.rb`

```
Refinery::Admin::PagesController.prepend(
  Module.new do
    def permitted_page_params
      super << :show_in_footer
    end
  end
)
```

Obviously heroku is having an issue with the prepend method, but I'm not sure how to make my footer action work without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ability to call private methods in ruby using [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-send). I am not sure, if this is intended to be used particularly here, but just change

```
Refinery::Admin::PagesController.prepend(MODULE_CODE)
```

to

```
Refinery::Admin::PagesController.send :prepend, MODULE_CODE
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for that!

Comment: I would put a caution: generally speaking, whether it was an expected control flow, Refinery’s authors should provide the public method to achieve that. So, it sounds like you are nailing screws with an iron :) Probably, you’d better try to lookup the documentation carefully to find _a proposed way to achieve what you wanted_. (I am not a guru in Refinery, so unfortunately I am unable to give an advice.)